# Matplotlib incomplete timestamps

Tags: python, matplotlib

Have been forced to reinstall work environment, and this has broken matplotlib.  It's gone from properly presenting timestamps to showing them like this:
[image: Example Graph]

Apologies for the terrible graph, but as you can see the timestamp has been cut from "28/11/2017 21:2x:xx" to "28 21:2x".  There have been no code changes.  What caused this?   How can I fix this??

Thanks

Edit to add:  Generating code, as requested

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
....SQL code removed....
fig = plt.figure()
host = fig.add_subplot(111)

par1 = host.twinx()

host.set_xlabel("Time")
host.set_ylabel("Temperature")
par1.set_ylabel("Voltage")

plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
host.plot(xList, yList)
par1.plot(xList2, yList2, 'r-')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.grid()
fig.savefig(SOURCE)
```

Edit 2: In what way is it different from linked question?  In the linked "duplicate", the question is how to change the formatting.  I want to understand why the formatting is now truncated.  Would be perfectly happy with the standard format... if it could be read.

Comment: Is this a guessing game: "What could be the code that I run such that this happens?" See [mcve].

Comment: Added code as requested.  I accept that it should have been there in the first place. I blame someone else :)

Comment: As in duplicate, but here you actually want the full format: `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))`

Comment: Full data isn't being displayed.  Format is irrelevant if it gets chopped off after xx characters.

Comment: The standard format *is* now `%d %H:%M` (depending on what range of data you show). There is nothing "chopped off". The linked question shows how to change that format to any other format.

Comment: Ahhhhh - the standard format has changed.  Stick that as an answer and I'd accept it.  That's where I was stuck.  Why has this behavour changed?

Comment: Final solution:  Turn on classic mode, details here: https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html

Comment: The reason to change it is not to have years and months sticking around in a graph that shows a timespan of 50 seconds or so.

Comment: I'm not arguing that it's a bad change - just that it can look like an error, if you weren't expecting it.  That it isn't an error is worth recording somewhere, for the next time someone else makes the same mistake.